# get data attribute value onclick link / button

Tags: jquery, html

```
<span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home" id="changeb" data-datac="daily"><i></i>Daily</span>
            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home" id="changeb" data-datac="1week"><i></i>1 Week</span>
            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home" id="changeb" data-datac="monthly"><i></i>Month</span>
            <span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home" id="changeb" data-datac="3Month"><i></i>3 Month</span>
```

the jquery is

```
$('#changeb').click(function() {

        var d = $(this).data('datac');      
        alert(d);   
} );
```

I need to get the data-datac value on click event ,

Comment: instead `id="changeb"` use `class="changeb"`

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your code is fine you have **same id for more then one element** which is not valid. The event will be binded to *first* element with given id in the `DOM`. Use common class instead of id to bind the event. You can use [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) to bind the event.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/422gv/)**

```
$('.btn').click(function() {
      var d = $(this).data('datac');      
      alert(d);   
});
```

Answer (score 9):

This should do the trick:

```
var d = $(this).attr("data-datac");
```

Also, you need to change your HTML to give each element a seperate id. But it can be a tedious task to bind click events for a number of different ids. So i'd bind it to a seperate class. For example:

**HTML**

```
<span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home dateChanger" id="changeb1" data-datac="daily"><i></i>Daily</span>
<span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home dateChanger" id="changeb2" data-datac="1week"><i></i>1 Week</span>
<span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home dateChanger" id="changeb3" data-datac="monthly"><i></i>Month</span>
<span class="btn btn-block btn-inverse btn-icon glyphicons home dateChanger" id="changeb4" data-datac="3Month"><i></i>3 Month</span>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(".dateChanger").click(function () {
    var d = $(this).attr("data-datac");
    alert(d);
});
```

Comment: instead of common __id__ use __class__ otherwise only first element will select

Answer (score 3):

You can get attribute values of an element using the `attr` in  `jquery` like

```
$('.home').on('click', function() {

    var d = $(this).attr('data-datac');      
    alert(d);   
});
```

F.Y.I

If you will use `id's` as selector you can only get one element while on a `class` you can get reference all the elements containing that class

Answer (score 1):

Its Simple....

```
 var data_value = $(this).attr("data-datac");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set all the elements a unique `id`. That's why it's happening only for the first element.

Answer (score 1):

Use a unique id for each element

```
var d=$(this).attr('data-datac');
```

Comment: `class` is the best way in this scenario